# Selecting fields from joined tables

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL.  I am trying to select some of the fields from 2 of 3 joined tables and all of the fields from a 3rd table.  Other than specifying each individual field from the Pr table, is the a simpler way to SELECT individual fields from two of the tables and SELECT * from the 3rd table.  My current query is below.  This is an exercise from a book.  If the 3rd table contained more fields this method would become very cumbersome.

```
 SELECT  Lo.City ,
        Em.FirstName ,
        Em.LastName ,
        Pr.EmpID ,
        Pr.YearlySalary ,
        Pr.MonthlySalary ,
        Pr.HourlyRate
FROM    Location AS Lo
        INNER JOIN Employee AS Em ON Lo.LocationID = Em.LocationID
        INNER JOIN PayRates AS Pr ON Em.EmpID = Pr.EmpID
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use `Pr.*` to select all columns from the table aliased `Pr`.

This is widely discouraged in production code however as if the table definition changes your query can suddenly start bringing back loads of irrelevant data that is not needed.